# How do I get Hibernate to store my BigDecimal wrapper object as a field easily?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, hibernate-mapping

I'm using a custom wrapper on a BigDecimal field:

```
public class MyCustomWrapper {
    private BigDecimal amount;

    public BigDecimal getAmount() {
        return amount;
    }
}
```

I want to store my objects as though they are a BigDecimal (in other words NUMERIC) when used in my entity objects. I use the wrapper frequently in my entities so I'm looking to know if there's a way I can do this without many annotations on my MyCustomWrapper fields.

Entity:

```
@Entity
public class MyEntity {
    private MyCustomWrapper amountOne;
    private MyCustomWrapper amountTwo;
    private BigDecimal bigDecimalAmount; // Hibernate knows to automatically create a NUMERIC field for this without additional annotations
}
```

Comment: https://thoughts-on-java.org/jpa-21-how-to-implement-type-converter/

Comment: Awesome, thank you @JBNizet